# looping through an object twice - php

Tags: php, zen-cart

I'm playing around with a zencart trying to make it do what I want but I've run out of ideas of what to Google.

When I query the DB using the zencart function the software returns an object which looks like:

```
queryFactoryResult Object
(
[is_cached] => 
[resource] => Resource id #117
[cursor] => 11
[EOF] => 
[fields] => Array
    (
        [products_id] => 5582
        [products_description] => description here
        [products_name] => Lucky magnet – Each petal...
        [products_type] => 1
        [products_quantity] => 0
        [products_image] => EachPetalMag.jpg
        [products_price] => 3.4000
        [products_status] => 1
        [products_ordered] => 14
        [master_categories_id] => 21
        [supplier_id] => 7
    )
)
```

I have to loop through once to count how many master_categories are there before I can do anything else:

```
while (!$products->EOF) {
  $products_count++;
  $supcats[$products->fields['master_categories_id']] = $products->fields['master_categories_id'];
  $products->MoveNext();
}
```

I then need to loop through the object again using the while loop like above, I've tried:

```
reset($products);
```

and

```
$products->EOF = FALSE;
```

but they don't work. Is there a way to do this with out having to send the query again?

Comment: Have you tried storing the data in an array and looping that array the second time? PDO for example has no way to rewind the result-set cursor.

Comment: You can step through the data once - count the number of master_categories and copy the data into an array as @rodneyrehm suggests as you go.

Comment: ZenCart doesn't have a function for setting the pointer back to the start without re-querying, or storing the info in an array.  There must be a better way of writing your logic that doesn't require looping through a resultset multiple times.

Comment: thanks guys, I just made the array while I looped the first time, no idea why I didn't think of that. d'oh! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular array-like operations on Zen Cart queryFactoryResult won't work as it's not an array, so this won't work:

```
reset($products);
```

To loop through the variable again use queryFactoryResult->Move(row_number) method:

```
$products->Move(0);
```